# How to send request use AngularJS use war name?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, maven

I wand to send request:

```
var response = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "/Test/hello",
        data: {
            action:"action",
        }
    });
```

where is  `/Test/` - my war name. But if I rename war, I will have an error. How to setting request use war name?

Note. **web.xml**

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Spring controller**

```
@Controller
public class ProjectController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/hello")
@ResponseBody
public String hello(@RequestBody JSONObject request) {
   return "hello@;
}
```

Comment: Hardcoding context name inside your client code is a very bad idea as it's a hidden dependency between your client and server code - changing the way you deploy your application will make application suddenly stop working.

Answer (score 1):

This highly rellies on your deploy process.

Servlet mapping which you have specified is added after the path of the deployed application It doesnt specify exact path on application server.

This situation occures if you deploy application on some specified name (ussually war name is used). 
But you can specify it on your own, I ussually deploy single app on the server to be sure its on /

Your angular application is served as normal static asset by resource servlet dispatcher on the particular url.

If you insist on deploying to the various names I would suggest using relative path. Angular SPA application runs on the particular url, so it will not change during its lifecycle.

So if you have your application deployed at /Test and hello REST contoller is on /Test/hello, you can use just `hello` as url

```
var response = $http({
    method: "post",
    url: "hello",
    data: {
        action:"action",
    }
});
```

If you still want to have absolute urls than you can modify some defined constant during deploy.
For that I would recomend you to define constant for base url in some separate config.

```
angular('YourModule')
 .constant('BASE_URL', '/Test');
```

Comment: You probably meant to say `url: "./hello"`?

Comment: Sorry, I have copied exact code for mistake. Now its correct.